# Node reference field options supplied by Views 3 work in preview, not in content

Tags: views, nodes, commerce

I am trying to associate a node with a product type in Drupal Commerce. It is like choosing a t-shirt color, but instead they are choosing a node they published as a product attribute.
 I'm using Views to filter for only nodes published by current user, then I click the check box "Enable this field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms" while editing this field type.

When I view this product display, the node reference selection box is there, but there are no selections aside from "-none-".

I have flushed the cache, multiple times; I run the cron tasks. I've done everything I thought I could do.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem. After some hours of googling, I found the solution in these issue reports.

- http://drupal.org/node/1306106
- http://drupal.org/node/1356006

What you basically need to do is to install the development snapshot (7.x-1.x-dev, 25 Dec 2011) of Drupal Commerce. The patch has already been committed there.